# JSON parsing error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

```
$val_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

I decoded a JSON array & stored it into a variable. JSON has data from server side.

When I var dump this array `var_dump($val_array);` I get:

```
{
    "groups": {
        "connect": "yes",
        "Name": "admin",
        "id": "1",
        "Groups": "1",
        "manage": "1",
        "Users": "1",
        "show": "1",
        "log": "1"
    }
}
```

And I check size of array.

```
$x=count($val_array); gives 1 as output
$x=count($val_array['groups']); gives 8 as output
```

And when I have more data in my database, JSON looks like this

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "connect": "yes",
        "Name": "admin",
        "id": "1",
        "Groups": "1",
        "manage": "1",
        "Users": "1",
        "show": "1",
        "log": "1"
    },
              {
        "connect": "no",
        "Name": "noadmin",
        "id": "2",
        "Groups": "2",
        "manage": "2",
        "Users": "2",
        "show": "2",
        "log": "2"
              }
```

] }

I want to show the values to an html table. I use a simple for loop.

```
$val_array = $val_array['groups'];

for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
{

$a= $val_array['connect'];
$b= $val_array['Name'];
$c= $val_array['id'];
$d= $val_array['Groups'];
$e= $val_array['manage'];
$f= $val_array['Users'];
$g= $val_array['show'];
$h= $val_array['log'];
}
```

What is the value of `$x` that I should use?

When I use `$x=count($val_array);` and if JSON has more than 1 data, error comes up. Undefined offset or something, if data is only 1, then it works.

When I use this `$x=count($val_array['groups']);` and if JSON data has 1 data, size is returned as 8.

When I used

```
$x=count($val_array['groups']);
```

and

```
var_dump($val_array);
```

I got: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` in my page

Size as 8.

```
array (size=1)
  'groups' => 
    array (size=8)
      'connect' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'admin' (length=10)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Groups' => string '1' (length=1)
      'manage' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Users' => string '1' (length=1)
      'show' => string '1' (length=1)
      'log' => string '1' (length=1)
```

as var_dump output.

Comment: your JSON in the second case is malformed. You need a comma after the closing `}` after groups

Comment: Can you show us `var_dump($val_array);` for second json string just after decoding it.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `for`.

Comment: Since when does `var_dump()` display associative arrays like that? It always puts the type of the data first, and shows arrays with `Array(size)` at the beginning, and `=>` between the keys and values, not `:`. That looks more like the original JSON than the output of `var_dump`.

Comment: Even with the comma added, it's still not valid JSON. `{ }` surrounds objects, every element has to be in the form `key: value`. You have no key for the second value. Are you sure it isn't `groups: [ { ... }, { ...} ]`?

Comment: I have added var_dump output. @Rikesh

Comment: I have added var_dump output. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @barmar pointed out, your JSON Data is malformed. If you have already the correct JSON format, you could just use it and loop it thru `foreach` to output it to a table. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$raw = '{ "groups":[ { "connect":"yes", "Name":"admin", "id":"1", "Groups":"1", "manage":"1", "Users":"1", "show":"1", "log":"1" }, { "connect":"no", "Name":"noadmin", "id":"2", "Groups":"2", "manage":"2", "Users":"2", "show":"2", "log":"2" } ]}';
$data = json_decode($raw, true);
$data = reset($data); // flatten
$headers = array_keys(reset($data)); // get the header and use it as your headings/headers

?>

<!-- simple foreach loop -->
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <!-- loop the headers -->
    <?php foreach($headers as $value): ?>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <!-- then loop the values -->
        <?php foreach($value as $element):?>
            <td><?php echo $element; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sH7uqo)

Answer (score 4):

If `groups` is supposed to be an array of group opbjects, the JSON should be:

```
{
   "groups":[
      {
         "connect":"yes",
         "Name":"admin",
         "id":"1",
         "Groups":"1",
         "manage":"1",
         "Users":"1",
         "show":"1",
         "log":"1"
      },
      {
         "connect":"no",
         "Name":"noadmin",
         "id":"2",
         "Groups":"2",
         "manage":"2",
         "Users":"2",
         "show":"2",
         "log":"2"
      }
   ]
}
```

You need `[ ]` around the array. With this JSON, `count($val_array['groups'])` should return `2`, not `8`. See this [demo](http://ideone.com/CwGAdE).

If the web service sometimes returns the groups as an array, and other times as a single element, you can do this:

```
if (!isset($val_array['groups'][0])) {
    $val_array['groups'] = array($val_array['groups']);
}
```

This checks whether groups is an array. If not, it makes an array containing the single element. Then you can process it consistently as an array in the rest of your code.

Comment: All I need is to know about the size. My JSON is corrected (I corrected it). @Barmar

Comment: This works fine. But thing is, I am getting this JSON when I make a GET request to a web service, so when there is only one element, there are no []. So I ain't able to change that manually. @Barmar

Comment: Don't use the `true` option to `json_decode`. Then you can test whether the type of of `$val_array->groups` is an array or an object.

Comment: If it's an array, you need to iterate over it, if it's an object you can access it directly.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array @ Barmar when I didn't use true option to json_decode.

Comment: That's because you have to use object notation for it. `$val_array->groups` instead of `$val_array['groups']`.

Comment: What web service is this? It's really a crime that it returns data in different formats depending on the number of groups. If this is something you've written, you should fix it.

Comment: I hope this works out. BTW, that web service wasn't written by me. It'a RESTful web service in Java. @ Barmar

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. change $val_array['Log'] to $val_array['log'].

```
$json_data = '{
   "groups": [{
   "connect": "yes",
   "Name": "admin",
   "id": "1",
   "Groups": "1",
   "manage": "1",
   "Users": "1",
   "show": "1",
   "log": "1"
},
 {
   "connect": "no",
   "Name": "noadmin",
   "id": "2",
   "Groups": "2",
   "manage": "2",
   "Users": "2",
   "show": "2",
   "log": "2"
}] }';

$val_array = json_decode($json_data, true);

foreach($val_array["groups"] as $key=>$value){

$a= $value['connect'];
$b= $value['Name'];
$c= $value['id'];
$d= $value['Groups'];
$e= $value['manage'];
$f= $value['Users'];
$g= $value['show'];
$h= $value['log'];
echo $h;
}
```